# Jquery ajax success or error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to implement a bootstrap login form. When the user submits, I am making an ajax call to submit to a Servlet where I can check for validity. If the userid and password are valid, I will redirect to home page. If not I would like to send JSON message back to screen.

How ajax knows the message I am sending back to the page is an error message or a success message?
How can I display that message on above  login field? Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#form-signin').validate({
    rules: {
        login: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true               
        },
        password: {
            minlength: 3,
            maxlength: 15,
            required: true                
        }
    },
    messages: {               //messages to appear on error
         login: {
             required:"Please Enter your user ID."                      
              },               
          password: {
              required: "Please Enter Password."                     
              }
        },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('has-error');
    },
    unhighlight: function (element) {
        $(element).closest('.control-group').removeClass('has-error');
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert("submit click");
                  $.ajax({
                   url:"/ePay/UserValidationServlet",
                  type:"POST",
                  dataType: "json",
                  data: $('#form-signin').serialize(),
                  error: function(errorMessage) {
                    console.log(errorMessage); // Optional
                    },
               success: function(response){
                   alert(response);
             }
           });
        }
});
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sTDcF/8/)

Comment: You have one of two options. **(1)** You send by the message and a code which you check for success or error manually in your success callback. **(2)** You send back a `401 Unauthorized` header from ***PHP*** which will cause the request to fall into the error callback.

Comment: @A.Wolff - Is that the correct way to do it? Should a validation error on the server return a 200 (OK) status? That is what I currently do, but I am wondering if that's the most appropriate way.

Comment: @JohnS I've seen it done both ways and I've done it both ways so I think it really depends on your use case. Even if I send a code back in my response, I usually find the appropriate web code and use it. This way, anyone who follows along behind me will essentially know what the error was. The problem I've run into, for example with sending back a `401` header, is that my custom error message was not returned. Not sure if this is a common problem or just one I had though.

Comment: You have to manually check for validation errors in your success callback. The `error:` method is only trigger when any error output by your header or server. E.g: `500 bad request`, `403 forbidden` etc..

Comment: I like the option 1 sending a message and code. I can send a code lets say 101.In success, how can I check 101 and put a custome message above the login field? Any sample code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
  mapper.writeValue(out, "101");//User id or password incorrect

Comment: my alert is showing 101. I need some smaple from herr.

Comment: @War10ck - Thanks for the reply. I will probably stay with what I show in my answer below, but it's annoying to document because it is a success (200) response that indicates a failure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way this can be done:

Place a hidden div where you want to display the error message:

```
<div id="errorMessage" style="display: none"></div>
```

Have the ajax call return a 200 (OK) status both when the form submission is successful and when there are validation errors. The response body should be JSON. (You are already indicating you are expecting JSON by setting `dataType: 'json'`.)

The returned JSON could look like this when there are no validation errors:

```
{ "success": true }
```

And like this for a validation error:

```
( "success": false, "message": "Authentication failed." }
```

Then your ajax success callback would look like this:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result.success) {
        // Handle the success result.
    } else {
        $('#errorMessage').html(result.message);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE** in response to comment:

I suppose the server could return a redirect when the form submission is successful, but it could also return:

```
{ "success": true, "redirectUrl": "/xxxxx" }
```

And then the success handler would be:

```
success: function(result) {
    if (result.success) {
        window.top.location = result.redirectUrl;
    } else {
        $('#errorMessage').html(result.message);
    }
}
```

There are times when a form is submitted via ajax, but a success should not result in a redirect. One situation is where the form is on a popover, and a successful form submission will just close the popover.

Comment: I am not quite understand what I should return from the servelet as jason that can come as response to success?

Comment: If the call is successful, control will not come to success event as serverlet will rediret the response to home page.

Comment: I have tried the code. Some reason it is going to else statement for the below message.LOG: {"success": true, "redirectUrl": "/ePay/home.jsp"}

Comment: further details, console.log(result.success);
 is undefined ??

Comment: I think my restult is coming as pure String value not jason object?. I may have to take a look.But if you have any suggestions to share tha twould be great.

Comment: Yes, I figured. I have converted String to jason as var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( result ); and it worked fine. Than kyou soooo much!!! Great help.